# Alamofire.request function is returning an error which says "extra argument in call"

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

```
request = Alamofire.request(.GET, recipe.foodImageUrl!).validate(contentType: ["image/*"]).response(completionHandler: { request, response, data, err in
       if err == nil {
            let img = UIImage(data: data!)!
            self.foodRecipeImg.image = img
            FeedVC.imageCache.setObject(img, forKey: recipe.foodImageUrl!)

        }
 })
```

When running this code, an error comes up which says there's an extra argument in call. After looking through other answers, I still can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

Alamofire 3 :

```
let strURL = recipe.foodImageUrl ! as String

    Alamofire.request(.GET, strURL).response { (request, response, data, error) in
         if error == nil {
                let img = UIImage(data: data!)!
                self.foodRecipeImg.image = img
                FeedVC.imageCache.setObject(img, forKey: recipe.foodImageUrl!)

            }
    }
```

Alamofire 4.0 :

```
Alamofire.request(strURL).response { response in // method defaults to `.get`
    if error == nil {
                    let img = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    self.foodRecipeImg.image = img
                    FeedVC.imageCache.setObject(img, forKey: recipe.foodImageUrl!)

                }
```

}

Comment: no that didnt work. The error still pops up saying extra argument in call

Comment: let strURL = recipe.foodImageUrl ! as String

Comment: and pass strURL instead of passing recipe.foodImageURL!

Comment: but that in turn wouldnt do anything. It would juts shorten the paramters name. I still tried it, but the error extra argument in call still popped up

Comment: He is using 3.0 syntax to call 4.0 API. So just take a look to the document i attached in my answer. Update the syntax , everything will be  fine.

Comment: When i tried it, the extra argument in call error went away, but then 2 new errors popped up. The first being "error becomes an unresolved indentifier", and where the "data!)! " part is concerned, the error is "Cannot convert value of type 'Data!.Type(aka implicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Aata>.type) to expected argument type 'Data'"

Comment: can you please add data like : resposne, data in

Answer (score 0):

Please try this variant. (updated)

```
request = Alamofire.request(recipe.foodImageUrl!) 
  .response { 
    response in 
    let img = UIImage(data: response.data!)! 
    self.foodRecipeImg.image = img 
    FeedVC.imageCache.setObject(img, forKey: recipe.foodImageUrl!) 
  }
```

Comment: As you are using 4.0, please try this `request = Alamofire.request(recipe.foodImageUrl!)
  .response {
    response in
      let img = UIImage(data: data!)!
      self.foodRecipeImg.image = img
      FeedVC.imageCache.setObject(img, forKey: recipe.foodImageUrl!)
  }`

Comment: when i do that, the only error that shows up is "use of unresolved identifier 'data'"

Comment: @Shaan Please replace `data` with `response.data`.

Comment: @Shaan Can you paste your final working code ? Will help folks following the thread or looking for solution.